# What happens if 2 players destroy each other's arena towers at the exact same time during overtime?

Tags: clash-royale

If 2 players destroy each other's king towers at the exact same time, it results in a 3-crown draw. But what happens if 2 players destroy each other's **arena** (not king, so no 3-crown) towers at the exact same time **during overtime?** Does it end in a draw, does overtime continue, or is there extra time added to overtime (probably not the last one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this happen and why I was searching to see how frequently it happens. At 50 seconds of overtime we each took a side tower at the exact same time. The clock kept running from where it was and 50 seconds later we ended up ending in a 1-1 draw.

Answer (score 5):

I seem to have been wrong with my previous opinion ("Can't happen").

If it happens during overtime it is again a **3-crown** draw: At 3.30

Comment: I'm curious, what makes it possible that it can't happen during overtime, but is allowed to happen in regular play?

Comment: @NBN-Alex As I said, it may look like it's happening at the same time, but even a split millisecond is enough to make a difference, and we wouldn't notice if one tower goes down a millisecond before the other one ... That's how computers work, they queue the actions they need to perform, and roughly each action takes a millisecond or two.

Comment: wait a moment though. While most games do use transnational updates (.00001 action A happens, .0002 action B happens) there's many other factors that can cause "double KO" to happen in different games.  Online Multiplayer games especially have checks and values built in to compensate for lag or temporary loss of connection. (especially if the player is switching from wifi to cell, or cell to cell, there's a mini-disconnect that's usually unnoticeable.) - OP States that the game already has a Double KO situation during normal play, so what is it about Overtime that prevents this from happening?

Comment: @NBN-Alex My Computer Science education misled me. My bad, I updated my answer with factual information.

Answer (score 2):

You can destroy each others towers at exactly the same time in overtime. Not king tower but the side ones. This happened to me, the clock just runs down for the remainder of the time and each player then tries to desctoy the king tower.

Answer (score 0):

Your can rarely tie 3-3 if both towers are taken down at the same time. However it is quite uncommon as usually one gets destroyed before the other, I believe that they changed it so you can tie in a update a month or two ago. But you can definitely tie!

Hope this helped!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! If you're so uncertain of your answer as to say "don't take my word on it", you probably shouldn't post the answer. If you *are* sure, but just want them to trust a source, then provide a source. Unlike most forums, we want answers to be definitive, and whenever possible should include either original research with test methods or citations of sources.

Comment: @DCShannon I answered what he asked about. I said don't take my word about which update its from.

Comment: @DCShannon wow why is everything of mine down voted... Now I can't post anything. Thanks guys

Comment: I didn't downvote, since you're a new user and this is your first post, and I want to give you an opportunity to figure things out. That being said, the downvotes are justified, mainly for the reasons I mentioned earlier. If you were only referring to *which* update when you expressed uncertainty, then you should edit your answer to make that clearer. That will probably help. You also don't seem to have actually answered the question. The asker wanted to know what happens in a certain scenario, and I understand your answer to simply say that that scenario doesn't usually happen.

Comment: @DCShannon alright thank you. I tried to say it can end in a 3-3 draw, but I guess I didn't explain very well. What can I do to try to start over? It's hard to do anything with all these downvotes. And I will edit my comment.

Comment: That's significantly better, and I threw you an upvote for the effort. Some people just rage quit and never come back once they receive any criticism at all. Still, if you look at the other answer, which has upvotes and will probably be accepted, you can see the difference. With your answer, we just have to take your word for it. With that other answer, there's video evidence of this occurring. Such strong evidence isn't always required, but it always helps, and an answer with evidence will beat one without every time. Again, welcome to Arqade.

Comment: @DCShannon okay thank you for the advice. I really appreciate it!  I will keep everything you told me in mind!